# Xcode(Swift) でSKSceneでSegueを使った画面遷移について

Tags: swift4, spritekit

<目的>
ViewControllerでGameSceneをpresentで表示させていて、そのGameSceneでのスコアを次のViewで表示させるためにGameSceneから元のViewControllerのSegueを使い次のViewを表示させたい。
<問題点>
ビルドに関しても問題なく作動するのだが、GameSceneでのGameOver時にボタンを生成し、そのボタンでSegueによる遷移を行おうとしているが、遷移しない。

ViewControllerB.swift

```
class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        let scene = GameScene()
        let view = self.view as! SKView

        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true

        scene.size = view.frame.size

        view.presentScene(scene)
    }   
}
```

GameScene.swift

```
class GameScene : SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var bowl:SKSpriteNode?

    var timer:Timer?

    var lowestShape:SKShapeNode?

    var score = 0
    var scoreLabel: SKLabelNode?
    var scoreList = [100,200,300,500,800,1000,1500]
    var viewController: UIViewController?

    override func didMove(to view: SKView){

        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: -2.0)
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        let background =  SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
        background.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.5, y: self.size.height*0.5)
        background.size = self.size
        self.addChild(background)

        let lowestShape = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: self.size.width*3, height: 10))
        lowestShape.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.5, y: -10)

        let physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: lowestShape.frame.size)
        physicsBody.isDynamic = false
        physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = 0x1 << 1
        lowestShape.physicsBody = physicsBody

        self.addChild(lowestShape)
        self.lowestShape = lowestShape

        let bowlTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bowl")
        let bowl = SKSpriteNode(texture: bowlTexture)
        bowl.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.5, y: 100)
        bowl.size = CGSize(width: bowlTexture.size().width*0.5, height: bowlTexture.size().height*0.5)
        bowl.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: bowlTexture, size: bowl.size)
        bowl.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        self.bowl = bowl
        self.addChild(bowl)

        var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Helvetica")
        scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.92, y: self.size.height*0.78)
        scoreLabel.text = "¥0"
        scoreLabel.fontSize = 32
        scoreLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.right
        scoreLabel.fontColor = UIColor.green
        self.addChild(scoreLabel)
        self.scoreLabel = scoreLabel

        self.fallNagoyaSpecialty()

        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(fallNagoyaSpecialty), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func fallNagoyaSpecialty() {
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(7))
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "\(index)")
        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
        sprite.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.5, y: self.size.height)
        sprite.size = CGSize(width: texture.size().width*0.5, height: texture.size().height*0.5)
        sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: texture, size: sprite.size)
        sprite.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0x1 << 1

        self.addChild(sprite)

        self.score += self.scoreList[index]
        self.scoreLabel?.text = "¥\(self.score)"
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            let action = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: location.x, y:100), duration: 0.2)
            self.bowl?.run(action)
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            let action = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: location.x , y:100), duration: 0.2)
            self.bowl?.run(action)
        }
    }

    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        if contact.bodyA.node == self.lowestShape || contact.bodyB.node == self.lowestShape{
            let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "gameover")
            sprite.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.5, y: self.size.height*0.5)
            self.addChild(sprite)

            self.isPaused = true
            self.timer?.invalidate()
            haveScore()
            let myButton = UIButton()
            myButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 40)
            myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            myButton.setTitle("次へ", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControl.State.normal)
            myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
            myButton.layer.position = CGPoint(x: self.view!.frame.width/2, y: 200.0)
            myButton.addTarget(self , action: #selector(self.next(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            self.view!.addSubview(myButton)     
        }
    }
    func haveScore() {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.message = score
    }

    @objc func next(sender: UIButton){

        self.viewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toFinish", sender: nil)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

「問題点」が生じる原因は、`GameScene`クラスのプロパティ`viewController`に対して、どこにも`UIViewController`クラスのインスタンスの参照が代入されていないことにあります。`viewController`の型はOptional型なので、デフォルト値は`nil`になります。
メソッド`next(sender: UIButton)`の実装内

```
self.viewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toFinish", sender: nil)
```

この行の中の`viewController`の値は、上に理由で`nil`なので、**Optional Chaining**の文法により、この行の実行が中断されます。すなわち画面遷移は起きません。
適切なタイミング（`ViewControllerB`において、`GameScene`インスタンスを生成した直後など）で、プロパティ`viewController`に代入をしてみてください。

もうひとつ気になるのは、クラス`GameScene`のプロパティ`viewController`の型が`UIViewController?`になっていることです。これはサブクラスの`ViewControllerB?`としなければ、セグエ`toFinish`を認識してもらえないのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 親切で丁寧な回答ありがとうございます！ご指摘通り、`GameScene`インスタンスを生成した後に、`viewController`に`ViewControllerB`を代入したらRunning中の**Thread1:signal SIGABRT**は解消されましたが、遷移はしないままでした。`ViewControllerB`の`presentScene`をコメントアウトし、`ViewControllerB`クラスで`performSegue`を行うとうまく遷移するのですが、`presentScene`をし、`GameScene`クラスでの`performSegue`では遷移しませんでした。

Comment: お返事、遅れてしまい申しわけ有りません。いただいたコメントの内容に合わせて、回答を補筆、編集いたしました。ご覧くださいませ。